# setupWithNavController(navController) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Android Studio is not recognising the correct import for `setupWithNavController(navController)`.

But it works in the Google I/O App:

https://github.com/google/iosched

I've created a hello world project where I've only added the `NavHostFragment`:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and these 3 libraries:

**build.gradle (app level):**

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        api "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
        api "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
        api "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
    }
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
}
```

The App doesn't see the `setupWithNavController` with `navController` as argument method. But in the Google I/O App it does.

I tried referencing the whole package name directly, but it only recognises the NavigationUI:
[image]

When I click on the import, I do see the correct library:

[image]

This is the correct class:
[image]

I tried Invalidate Cache / Restart and Clean, build all but no success.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation) how to add Navigation related dependencies in **build.gradle**

Comment: u need a `navigationView` to use `setupWithNavController`

Comment: `setupWithNavController` is an extension on a `BottomNavigationView`. You're trying to call it on `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need navigation View to use setup nav controller look like this hope helpful

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.yourpackagename

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
 
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml
[image: main_activity.xml]